# How can I accomodate category names also to the magento quick search?

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, search-criteria

I am new to magento2, I wanted to know how we can bring category names also to the quick search. For eg: When I search using a keyword 'Bag', I should get a list off all products under the category "Bag" + all products that have the keyword 'bag' in its title , description or SKU.
Thanks

Comment: you can check this questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579630/search-by-category-name http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91288/search-category-names-in-basic-search-and-return-matching-products http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100937/include-category-in-search-result

Comment: did you finally find a solution to do this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need the category name indexed in the product search.
It is quite complicated to have an index which is always up to date (especially when you are editing a category, you need to reindex all products belonging to this category).

You may also try our ElasticSuite module (https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite), which bring this feature enabled out of the box.